# How to write matrix in equation environment?

Tags: equations

I'm using LaTeX to write my paper and every equation needs to be numbered, so I use the `equation` environment. However, it fails to compile.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    L_{a1} & 0 \\
    0 & L_{a2} 
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    I_{a1}  \\
    I_{a2}
\end{bmatrix}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
    R_{a1} & 0 \\
    0 & R_{a2} 
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    I_{a1}  \\
    I_{a2}
\end{bmatrix}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
    K_{e1} & 0 \\
    0 & K_{e2} 
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    $theta_1$ \\
    $theta_2$
\end{bmatrix}
=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    V_{a1} \\
    V_{a2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

So my question is: how to revise it? In addtion, I would like to know why the math expression that follows is wrong:

```
$$ B = \frac{J_2}{N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_2^2}{4 N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_1 r_2}{2 N_1 N_2} cos(\frac{\theat_{m2}}{N_2}) $$
$$ C = \frac{-m_2 r_1 r_2}{N_1 N_2}(\frac{\theat_{m1} \theat_{m2}}{N_1}+\frac{\theat_{m2}^2}{2 N_2}) sin\frac{\theat_{m2}}{N_2} $$
$$ D = J_{m1} +\frac{J_2}{N_2^2}+\frac{m_2 r_2^2}{4 N_2^2} $$
$$ E = \frac{J_2}{N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_2^2}{4 N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_1 r_2}{2 N_1 N_2} cos(\frac{\theat_{m2}}{N_2}) $$
```

LaTeX gives the information:

```
Undefined control sequence. [..._2}{2 N_1 N_2} cos(\frac{\theat_{m2}}{N_2}]
```

Comment: `\theta` not `\theat`. Also you don't need `\[ \]` inside `equation` environment.

Comment: And for the last bit, don't use `$$ ... $$`. See e.g. [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Also remove `$` from inside `bmatrix` (you are already in math mode). Also you probably want `\theta` and not `theta`

Comment: Since you're just starting to learn LaTeX I recommend that you write your math just a little bit at a time, compiling often. That way your mistakes will show up just one at a time and will be easier to find and fix. When you're stuck after trying, ask here, one question at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should work. Changes:

- deleted `\[` in line 8
- deleted `\]` in line 40
- deleted `$` in lines 32 and 33 -> you're already in a math environment, so you don't need to mark this as a math environment by using `$ .. $`
- added `\` in front of `theta` in lines 32 and 33

  ```
  \documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
      L_{a1} & 0 \\
      0 & L_{a2} 
  \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
      I_{a1}  \\
      I_{a2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  +
   \begin{bmatrix}
      R_{a1} & 0 \\
      0 & R_{a2} 
  \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     I_{a1}  \\
      I_{a2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  +
   \begin{bmatrix}
      K_{e1} & 0 \\
      0 & K_{e2} 
  \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \theta_1 \\
      \theta_2
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     V_{a1} \\
      V_{a2} 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
  \end{document}
  ```

Regarding your equations:
You wrote `theat` instead of `theta` -> changing that should do it:

```
    $$ B = \frac{J_2}{N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_2^2}{4 N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_1 r_2}{2 N_1 N_2} cos(\frac{\theta_{m2}}{N_2}) $$
    $$ C = \frac{-m_2 r_1 r_2}{N_1 N_2}(\frac{\theta_{m1} \theta_{m2}}{N_1}+\frac{\theta_{m2}^2}{2 N_2}) sin\frac{\theta_{m2}}{N_2} $$
    $$ D = J_{m1} +\frac{J_2}{N_2^2}+\frac{m_2 r_2^2}{4 N_2^2} $$
    $$ E = \frac{J_2}{N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_2^2}{4 N_1 N_2}+\frac{m_2 r_1 r_2}{2 N_1 N_2} cos(\frac{\theta_{m2}}{N_2}) $$
```